# Installing typescript 1.3 questions

Tags: installation, typescript

Followed the [link listed here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-typescript-1-3.aspx)

We're having trouble installing (I think).

We installed for VS2013 - how can we find out what version it is using? Compile output does not show anything for tsc.

And how do we use it from the command line? 1.0 & 1.1 installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript but this does not. I did the nodejs install and it has C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules.bin\tsc.cmd - is that the correct way to call it now?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit confusing but notice the following output

```
PS C:\Users\dvdbrink> (get-command tsc.exe).path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1\tsc.exe
PS C:\Users\dvdbrink> tsc.exe -v
message TS6029: Version 1.3.0.0
```

So the tsc.exe in the 1.1 folder is actually 1.3

Not really sure why the folder/version numbering is off but this is the case for me.
Small sidenote: I'm a bit confused too because on another system it isn't working like this (still showing 1.0.3) but you might want to check your `tsc.exe -v` from the 1.1 directory

Answer (score 1):

See this post for details on the SDK folder name to version mapping:

[TypeScript 1.3 for Visual Studio 2013 missing SDK directory (tsc.exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898185/typescript-1-3-for-visual-studio-2013-missing-sdk-directory-tsc-exe/26915217#26915217)

See this post for details on figuring out which version is getting picked up:

[TypeScript 1.3 protected error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929051/typescript-1-3-protected-error/26935049#26935049)